# Django - Following A Foreign Key To Another Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

---

I'm trying to speedup lookups on my models. I have 3 models.

```
class sett(models.Model):
    setid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    block = models.ForeignKey(mapt, related_name='sett_block')

class data_parsed(models.Model):
    setid = models.ForeignKey(sett, related_name='data_parsed_setid', primary_key=True, db_index = True)
    setid_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True)

class unique_variables(models.Model):
    setid = models.ForeignKey(sett, related_name='unique_variables_setid', db_index = True)
    setid_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index = True)
```

---

Most importantly, sett has a primary key called setid, which:

data_parsed, and unique_variables have a foreign key to setid

data_parsed: 3 million rows

unique_variables: 13 million rows

---

Then I have some piece of code that tries to iterate through all data_parsed objects.

```
def something_1():
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(0,N) <---- N is predefined, and no less than 10
        for contents in data_parsed.objects.all().iterator():
            pass
    timeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
    print str(timeEnd - timeNow)
```

data_parsed has a few million items, and it takes around 20 seconds to go through, which I think is pretty fast.

---

Now, since setid is the same fields on both data_parsed, and unique_variables. I can get items in unique_variables with the foriegn key of data_parsed. Hence:

```
def something_2():
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range (0, N) <---- N is predefined, and no less than 10
        for contents in data_parsed.objects.all().iterator():
            try:
                items = unique_variables.objects.get(setid = contents.setid)
            except:
                pass
    timeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
    print str(timeEnd - timeNow)
```

However, the problem is that this suddenly consumes hours of time. Since I cannot use select_related, since I'm not going back to sett, but actually moving from sett to unique_variables.

Is there a way to speed up getting items with this behavior?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). I've linked the docs for you.

```
def something_2():
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range (0, N) <---- N is predefined, and no less than 10
        parsed_objects = data_parsed.objects.all().prefetch_related(
            'setid__unique_variables_setid')
        for contents in parsed_objects:
            try:
                items = list(contents.setid.unique_variables_setid.all())
            except:
                pass
    timeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
    print str(timeEnd - timeNow)
```

Comment: For my own curiosity - isn't `prefetch_related()` more suitable for a `ManyToMany` field, and  `select_related()` more suitable for `ForeignKey`?

Comment: Yes if you're talking about a forward relationships, but you're using a ForeignKey to a reverse ForeignKey. The reverse of a ForeignKey is Many:1, which is similar to a ManyToMany. One ```sett```'s can have multiple ```unique_variables``` referencing it. That's why the ```prefetch_related``` needs to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was able to get a search from 1 hour to 20 minutes. I really appreciate your help!